# CSS word-break gives error

Tags: css, word-break

```
.word-break {
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

**Source :** [CSS-TRICKS](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/)

I have used above for word break.But it's giving below mentioned error.

**Note :** My Editor is VS 2013

[image]

So how can I get rid of the above error ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why you can use 2 time `word-break` in `.word-break` class `word-break: break-all;` and  `word-break: break-word;`??

Comment: break-word is not a standardised value for word-break. Remove the line. Text breaks between words by default.

Comment: I think, it's ok,  your editor do not have excellent support for all hacky ways :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get rid of the error message in a browser’s console by removing the declaration `word-break: break-word;`. This declaration, in addition to being invalid according to [CSS Text Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/) LC, is actively harmful. Ignored by most browsers, it appears to be recognized by Chrome, presumably so that `break-word` is taken the same as or similar to the initial value `normal`, overriding the preceding declaration.

Note that the `hyphens` declarations in this rule have no effect under any normal circumstances. The `word-break: break-all` declaration tells the browser that it may break arbitraril y anywhere, so it has no reason to try any hyphenatio n.

Answer (score 1):

The value `break-word` is invalid for the `word-break` property.

I think that what you are looking for is the `break-word` value for the `word-wrap` property

Please refer to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/) for more details

Your CSS must look like this:

```
.word-break {
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Comment: Using `word-wrap` would be pointless here, since it specifies permitted emergency breaking, whereas `word-wrap: break-word` permits any breaking, whether an emergency (line overflow) occurs or not.

Comment: Your answer was the only one relevant to me and saved my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you are using a wrong value that is why you get the error, `word-break` property only have the following values  :)

```
word-break: normal|break-all|keep-all|initial|inherit;
```

`normal` is the Default value. Break words according to their usual rules